# Express - Rate limit calls per user per time

Tags: express

I'm using express for my backend apis, is there anyway to limit requests per user ? for example a user can only make 10 requests per min ?, i'm JWT so what i have got about the user is his unique token

Comment: [`express-rate-limit`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit) is a popular package that limits based on IP.

Comment: Yes, there are lots of ways to rate limit.  Asking for a particular module to do that is "off-topic" here on stack overflow.  If you want to read about rate limiting algorithms to implement one yourself, you can start here with the [leaky bucket algorithm](https://www.google.com/search?q=leaky+bucket+algorithm) and there are many more algorithms you can find with an inclusive search on rate limiting algorithms.